# Exception when saving securityContext to SecurityContextRepository

Tags: spring-security, jersey, security

Started to secure some of my resful server resources using Spring Security.
My client is using ajax (jquery ajax) for the requests and I started by implementing the login functionality.

My Jersey web layer includes the following:

```
@Path("/login")
@Component
public class LoginResourceProvider extends ServiceResourceProvider {

    /*--- Static ---*/

    private final static ILogger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LoginResourceProvider.class);

    /*--- Members ---*/

    @Inject
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Inject
    protected SecurityContextRepository repository;

    @Inject
    protected RememberMeServices rememberMeServices;

    /*--- Constructors ---*/

    public LoginResourceProvider() {
    super("Login");
    }

    /*--- Public Methods ---*/

    @GET
    public void login() {
    }

    /**
     * A user login attempt
     * 
     * @param username
     *            The user name
     * @param password
     *            The password of the given user name
     * @param request
     * @param response
     * @return A JSON string, indicating if the login is successful
     */
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String performLogin(@QueryParam("j_username") String username, @QueryParam("j_password") String password,
        @Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {

    // Create a token
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();

    try {
        // Attempting to authenticate the user
        Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);

        // Updating the SecurityContext, which represents the user's
        // secured, authenticated session
        securityContext.setAuthentication(auth);

        // If the user authenticates successfully then the authentication
        // storing the security context in the HttpSession between requests
        repository.saveContext(securityContext, request, response);

        // object is passed to the remember-me service
        rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, auth);

        // Successfully authenticated
        return "{\"status\": true}";

        // Bad Credentials
    } catch (BadCredentialsException ex) {
        return "{\"status\": false, \"error\": \"Bad Credentials\"}";
    }
    }
}
```

My security-context.xml is pretty basic for now, just enough to test my the login process:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <form-login />
    <remember-me />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/secured/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Is it a good practice? I mean, I could not find lot's of "non-auto" login for ajax style requests there.
2. I'm getting an exception when trying to save the security context to the SecurityContextRepository, in this line:

   repository.saveContext(securityContext, request, response);

When I'm trying to log in using bob as username and bobspassword password the authentication goes smoothly but while debugging this specific line I'm jumping to a ClassCastException with the message:

```
$Proxy31 cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it.

According to [Spring documentation](http://www.scribd.com/doc/37188125/Spring-Security) authentication is done using the following steps:

1. The username and password are obtained and combined into an instance of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (an instance of the Authentication interface, which we saw earlier).
2. The token is passed to an instance of AuthenticationManager for validation.
3. The AuthenticationManager returns a fully populated Authentication instance onsuccessful  authentication.
4. The security context is established by calling SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(...) , passing in the returned authentication object.

In addition to the above steps, I also tried to store the SecurityContext in between requests by saving it to the SecurityContextRepository.
The responsibility for storing the SecurityContext between requests should fall to the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter which in it's turn invokes this operation, so no need for me to do it manually, I guess I should only stick to the above 4 steps.

UPDATE: I guess I tried implementing on my own something that Spring-Security already implements for me. I do not recommend following this approach, Spring-Security offers a much more simple practice.